# Convert foreach to variable assign when returning a Tuple

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, return-value

Using .NET Framework 4.7.2, I have a function that returns a Tuple and the returned values are then passed to another function in a foreach loop:

```
foreach ((var price, var discount) in Calculator.Compute(period, calculationComponent))
 {
  var rows = CreateCalculationRows(price, discount, otherParameters);
 }
```

The `Compute` function is declared as follow:

```
public static IEnumerable<(Price price, DiscountInfo discount)> Compute(Price price, CalcComponent calcComponent) { 
  ...
}
```

The code works fine, but I want to remove the foreach loop, since the Calculator.Compute() function, under some specific conditions that are always true in this specific case, returns a single row. I cannot simplify the Compute() return object, because it is used in many other functions.

How do I change the code to remove the foreach, so that the CreateCalculationRows() receives the parameters correctly ?

Comment: (Note, you can write `var (price, discount) ...`, which is slightly shorter)

Comment: You could use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` or something, but I think it would be a better idea to create a new method for Compute that only returns a single tuple instead of an IEnumerable to keep your code self-describing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd expect something like this to work - just taking a single result and deconstructing that:

```cs
(var price, var discount) = Calculator.Compute(period, calculationComponent).Single();
var rows = CreateCalculationRows(price, discount, otherParameters);
```